# Retrieving columns based on condition in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say that I have the following data frame in pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, False], 'B':[False, True], 'C':[True, True], 'D':[False, False], 'E':[False, False]})
```

How can I get only the columns that are True? I have a DataFrame with 2000+ columns filled only with `False` and `True` values and for each row I would like to get the `True` columns.

Comment: Just to clarify, what's your expected output for your example?

Comment: for instance I would like to get for row 0 the list ['A', 'C'] and row 1 the list ['B', 'C']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any row in your DataFrame `df` as a Boolean index for the column labels, `df.columns`. This returns an `Index` object containing only the "true" columns:

```
>>> df.columns[df.loc[0]]
Index([u'A', u'C'], dtype=object)
```

Since this is an `Index` object not a Python list, you can use `tolist()` to turn it into one:

```
>>> df.columns[df.loc[0]].tolist()
['A', 'C']
```

Comment: Not sure you need the `values`; in current `pandas`, it looks like `tolist` is a method of `Index`.

Comment: @DSM Thanks! I'd never checked that before. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use [row][column]-structure. The following piece of code should work:

```
>>> dictionary = {'A': [True, False], 'B':[False, True], 'C':[True, True], 'D':[False, False], 'E':[False, False]}
>>> itemList = list(dnaComplements.items())
>>> [x[0] for x in itemList if x[1][1] == True]
```

will return

```
>>>    ['B', 'C']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna know which column has all True:

```
>>> L = pd.DataFrame({'A': [True, False], 'B':[False, True], 'C':[True, True], 'D':[False, False], 'E':[False, False]})

>>> L
       A      B     C      D      E
0   True  False  True  False  False
1  False   True  True  False  False

>>> M = lambda x: x.all()
>>> P = L.apply(M)
>>> L = [ col for col in dict(P) if P[col]]
>>> L
['C']
```